# PHP Table. Displaying multiple rows into one

Tags: php, html-table

Here is my code:

```
    <table border="2px solid #FFF" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%"><Center>Username:</Center><br /></td>
                <td width="50%"><center>Numebr Of Warnings:</center><br /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <?
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM warnings");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if($numrows != "0"){
                   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        $warned = $row['username'];
                        $by = $row['by'];
                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM warnings WHERE username='$warned'");
                        $warns = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                        ?>
                            <table border="2px solid #FFF" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%"><center><b><?php echo $warned; ?></b></center></td>
                                    <td width="50%"><center><b><?php echo $warns; ?></center></b></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        <?php
                   }
                }
                else
                    echo "No Currently Warned Users";
                ?>

            <hr />
```

And here is the result: [image]

How can I make it so that instead of showing the 2 results for the user Mrg..... I just want it to show one result with the number or rows there are.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "php table". What you should is a html table.

Comment: use `group by` with a `sum` function

Comment: What is the structure of your table?

Comment: by = varch (255). id = int. username = varchar (255). date = datetime

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT` in your query to avoid duplicate rows in your results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username, `by` FROM warnings
```

Comment: This added the 2 and the 1 to make three for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Change the mysql_fetch_assoc with mysql_feth_array

You're getting the user with double record. Then for each user you are getting 2 lines

The best way to check it is to add pseudo-points to your code.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM warnings");
$arr=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $arr[]=$row;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);    
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

Here check if the $arr has double entries. Then change the mysql_fetch_assoc with mysql_fetch_array and try again

Comment: Sorry don't follow fully. What about echoing the table?

Comment: You can see if your array has double entries from records. I think the mysql_fetch_assoc when you're selecting records from db getting double records. If you have still problem I can help you with teamviewer or anything you need.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain... could you write the full code out for me including the table so I can understand and learn from it? Sorry. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I'm trying to help people. Please write the table struct here. I'll write the code for you.

Comment: by = varch (255). id = int. username = varchar (255). date = datetime.  Only by and username are needed :). THANKS!

Comment: Sorry for the late response , see my second answer for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the table

(by,id,username,date)

a1,1,u1,date

a2,2,u2,date

a3,3,u2,date

a4,4,u2,date

And here is the php code

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysqli_select_db($conn,"dbname");

$warns = mysqli_query($conn,"select username, count(username) as warncount  from dtest.warnings W group by username");

while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($warns))
{
    echo $line['username']." has ".$line['warncount']. " warns <br/> ";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but got this error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/cocpages/public_html/mods.php on line 40. I did change the db connect files

Comment: try directly my code. Create a table with the above structre and check. If you need I can show you on my computer. Don't worry I'm not hacker, cracker :)

Comment: Didn't mean files I just connected to my DB. Table structure is correct. Might do a Teamviewer in a bit if no solution. Can we do a private chat here? Could you make one? :)

Comment: I'm here. I've gone out. Are you there ?

Comment: I'm here. Any idea on what we can do? I am thinking of changing the table so that instead of inserting a new row it updates the current one to add 1 to the current value if the username exists in the table

Comment: Sorry. I haven't reputation for chat :(. I have only 9. Can you send me a mail to moutlou@outlook.com and I'll send you the TW username and password.

Comment: I got it with changing the DB and some stuff. Could you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944697/php-forums-with-current-database-what-to-choose

Thanks :)

Comment: This question has been marked as off-topic. To migrate users from your system to phpbb is hard. You must know all the phpbb system and encoding on password store. It isn't basic :)